# Android application certificate validity

Tags: android, certificate

Is it possible to change the validity of a certificate?

**key-a:has validity of 2 years. 

apk-a:signed with key-a.

apk-b:signed with ? which has 25 years validity.**

apk-a and apk-b are the same applications with the same package name.

Suppose there is a user who has installed apk-a on his cell phone.How can i make it possible for him to install apk-b as an update.

Here what i have tried so far:
**1.)I tried using keytool the expand the validity of the existing key with the below command.** 

*keytool -selfcert -v -alias mycertalias -validity 80000 -keystore teststore.jks -storepass mypassword*  

**result:** apk-b which is signed with this key cannot be installed on the cell phone.(requires previous one to be uninstalled.)

**2.)I have created key-b which has a validity of 25 years.
and signed the apk-b with both keys.**

result:same as above.

ps 1: I have tested these on samsung galaxy i7500.(which has android 1.6 installed on it)
ps 2: My application is on a website.I got nothing to do with android market.

Comment: The last remark: so this is your own, self-signed certificate not an official Android store certificate? Why not just generate a new one? But isn't the issue that the public keys of the certificates are different not the validity period?

Comment: I dont want to generate a new key.If i do that existing users must uninstall the application(which is signed with 2 year validity) before installing the new app.(which is singed with 25 year validity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose there is a user who has installed apk-a on his cell phone.How can i make it possible for him to install apk-b as an update.

That is not possible, sorry. They will need to uninstall the old application and install the new one.